# Modifying Complex Eigenvalues of Real Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a system for modifying eigenvalues that denoises them. It modifies the spectrum of a real symmetric matrix (representing a linear dynamical system), and then reconstructs the system. I want to apply my method to modifying matrices with complex eigenvectors.

The problem is, if I modify the phase of or magnitude of specific values, the reconstruction will no longer be real. How do people usually deal with this?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question...

Comment: What additional information do you need? Let's say I have an NxN matrix A. Let's say its eigenvalue phases form some curve. Let's say I analyze out of sample data and find there is a better curve that would make for a better fit. I replace the original spectrum with the new one. This works great for a symmetric matrix. For a matrix with complex eigenvalues, this won't reconstruct to a real system.

Comment: You can always modify your matrix to the identity matrix, but you are obviously not doing that because presumably there are some constraints you want to enforce. What are they? Are you trying to optimize anything?

Comment: I'm running a VAR(1) model. I'm trying to find the eigenvalues that maximize historical R2 assuming I cannot modify my eigenvectors (the eigenvectors are too high-dimensional to modify with my technique). In the symmetric case I just provide a new set and reconstruct. Does that make sense?

Comment: How much do you modify these eigenvalues? The obvious thing to do is to take your new non-real matrix and take its real part - that will work fine if the modifications are small.

Comment: I'm modifying them a lot. I've essentially found a monotonic relationship between the phase of the eigenvalues and the variance of the vectors they represent. I measure the values out of sample with respect to the vectors, and then I use this out of sample measure combined with the monotonic relationship to pick a new real spectrum.

In the complex case there are two issues. You've suggested a way to fix the first. The second is I'm not sure how to generalize my idea to account for the fact that there are complex conjugates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123256/discussion-between-james-pinkerton-and-igor-rivin).